# Keycloak WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource

Tags: openshift, single-sign-on, keycloak, redhat, redhat-containers

I'm trying to run rh-sso-7/sso74-openshift-rhel8 container in Openshift and it says the following:

```
13:03:20,612 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=web/transport=jgroups' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.jgroups.default-channel-factory; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /subsystem=jgroups
13:03:20,613 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=server/transport=jgroups' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.jgroups.default-channel-factory; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /subsystem=jgroups
13:03:20,614 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=keycloak/transport=jgroups' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.jgroups.default-channel-factory; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /subsystem=jgroups
13:03:20,614 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=ejb/transport=jgroups' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.jgroups.default-channel-factory; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /subsystem=jgroups
13:03:20,614 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=hibernate/transport=jgroups' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.jgroups.default-channel-factory; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /subsystem=jgroups
13:03:20,716 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Please, help.

Comment: The logs you posted are not that much helpful. The actual reason is an error that has happened before these lines.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this, how?